# Is it always a bad sign to have a question with views and zero interactions?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

This is the first time I found myself in this situation (I remembered now it is not the first `:)`). [My last bountied question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562979/2288) has a compilable MWE with clear explanation and inquiries. However, I received no comment/answer/upvote/downvote.

So, does it mean that the question is not interesting or worth putting effort into enough? Or may it mean that no answer is available at the moment?

Comment: I don't think a situation like this necessarily means that the question is not interesting. For the particular question that you mention here I did read it, I found it interesting, but I didn't know the answer and I also could not think of an obvious way to investigate, so I decided to skip the question. Part of that decision was also that I expected that Joseph Wright would answer, because he is the `siunitx` maintainer, and his answer would be better/faster/less effort from him then it would have been for me, compared to an answer I would write myself.

Comment: @Marijn Happy to know that. I thought the question is so trivial that everyone doesn't care to interact with `:)`